# Excel VBA sharing addins between different read-only instances of same workbook

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

My team and I share this workbook on a network drive. This workbook utilizes a few custom add-ins necessary for some custom functionality. These add-ins get automatically installed by custom VBA code I have added without any action on the part of the user. It seems that only I can use the add-ins - other team members have problems trying to load the add-ins, they get this error:

```
Run-time error 1004 Unable to copy add-in to library.
```

The error occurs when trying to run

```
Application.AddIns.add(<addin_name>)
```

The add-ins are located only on the Windows network share. I've written the code to ignore the prompt for copying the add-in to addins folder on local drive, because I don't want this to happen. This is a very annoying problem because I cannot debug it fully myself, I need the cooperation of my team members which is limited. Help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing problem may be that only one person can load the add-in at a time so each person needs a local copy? In that case, can the add-in be loaded for read-only so that more than one person can open it from the same location? Or if the local copy is the only solution, how to update the local copy each time they load the workbook?

Comment: Don't get mad at me for asking a simple question, but why not just copy the code from the add-ins to this particular workbook?  Add-ins are typically opened when you open an instance of Excel, so, therefore, they have to be installed on the local user's machine (my guess is since you designed the add-ins, they are already running in the background of your machine).  If the add-ins are designed to be used across multiple files, you might want to look into a different distribution technique than a multi-user shared file.

Comment: No problem, I should have mentioned it. Basically Excel has piss poor support for people working concurrently on the same workbook. To best get around this, each team member is assigned a worksheet in a workbook, and through a remote workbook they "commit" changes to this worksheet, which only takes a few seconds. All these remote workbooks share very similar code, and thus there are add-ins for that. Furthermore, there are other teams that want a variation of this project, so the workbook itself needs an add-in. Then there are add-ins shared by both the primary workbook and the remote ones.

Comment: That said, it seems like you can easily get around the problem of each team member having a local copy simply by making the add-in read-only, since there's no limit to how many people can read a document at the same time. That way, I only need to modify code in a single document that gets broadcast to the entire team and I don't have to constantly replace their local copies with a more up to date version. But I wouldn't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest just opening the XLA read-only from the network drive as if it was a workbook (which of course it is) rather than using Addins.Add - opening an XLA makes it available to the Excel session so it will function as an addin without being in the addins collection.

Comment: Yes, that is what we have. The shared addin is stored on a, um, share, with read-only flag set on the file. The Excel books that need the addin just have a reference to it, set from Tools - References in the VBA editor. Saved once, it persist. No need to load or check for presence. And the read-only flag allows debugging and changing the addin while it is loaded on some other PCs (obviously, they will not see the changes until they restart Excel).

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea it was that easy. Simple and elegant. I was led to believe everything had to go through Excel's addin API. I owe ya one, thanks!